# remove html special characters remove not working

Tags: php, html, special-characters

I have a string `examples’s` and I am trying to remove `’` or replace with its HTML code but this code is not working for me:

```
html_entity_decode(htmlentities("examples’s"))
```

Output shows this `examples�` in browser.

Comment: `html_entity_decode` is the inverse of `htmlentities`. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Gumbo: I would guess they want to make sure that input=output.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [htmlentities](http://us.php.net/htmlentities) with `ENT_QUOTES` options.

```
echo htmlentities("examples’s", ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: *ENT\_QUOTES*  does only affect `'` (U+0027) but not `’` (U+2019).

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<?php
echo htmlentities("examples’s", ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
echo html_entity_decode(htmlentities("examples’s", ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"),ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're having a problem with encoding. Try this

```
html_entity_decode(htmlentities("examples’s", ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'), ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')
```

Don't know what you wan't to do that for though.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not quite sure what you’re trying to accomplish. But here’s an explanation for the result you are getting:

[`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) is the inverse of [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities). So, provided that you’re using an appropriate character encoding, the following should be true:

```
$str === html_entity_decode(htmlentities($str))
```

That you’re getting this `�` instead implies that you’re using UTF-8 or another Unicode character encoding for your output as Unicode uses `�` as replacement for invalid byte sequences.

What probably happened is: You are using a single-byte character encoding in your PHP file so that `’` (U+2019) is encoded with a single byte like [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) does (0x92). With ISO 8859-1 as the default character set for `htmlentities`, that `’` is *not* turned into a entity reference as 0x92 is not a valid character in ISO 8859-1. Applying `html_entity_decode` on that won’t change anything. But interpreting it with UTF-8 results in an invalid byte sequence (i.e. that 0x92 byte that wasn’t changed) and the replacement character `�` is shown instead.

So when using `html_entity_decode` or `htmlentities` always specify the character encoding unless it’s actually ISO 8859-1. In you case the following *could* work:

```
html_entity_decode(htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'cp1252'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')
```

But for a simple encoding conversion you could also use [`iconv`](http://php.net/iconv) or [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding) instead.